# Redirect - remove custom query string

Tags: redirect, htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with some page URLs.
The page URL structure is like this:

```
www.example.com/wp/custom-taxonomy/somepagename/?token=12345
```

I want that when I access the URL above to redirect me to:

```
www.example.com/wp/custom-taxonomy/somepagename/
```

In `/wp/` is WordPress installed. I tried this in `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteCond %{query_string} ^token=12345
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it redirects me to:

```
www.example.com/custom-taxonomy/somepagename
```

Any ideas?

**Later edit**:

`/wp/` - the folder where Wordpress is installed;

`/custom-taxonomy/` - a custom taxonomy, like `/partners/` where I enter all my partners.

`/somepagename` - a dynamic page, like `/xyz-ltd`, `/abcd...` dynamic pages created for the custom taxonomy.

I can not put a rule for every page, would need a general rule to remove the query string.

Comment: i think its your Rewritebase conflicting with the condition and final rule. Sorry ive been too heavy on IIS these days to provide a real answer

Comment: It has nothing to do with `RewriteBase`. In the above directives the `RewriteBase` directive is entirely superfluous - it's not being used. @BrandtSolovij

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteBase /wp/
> RewriteCond %{query_string} ^token=12345
> RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
> ```
>
> but it redirects me to:
>
> ```
> www.example.com/custom-taxonomy/somepagename
> ```

There are two issues here with the redirected URL:

1. The `/wp` prefix is missing.
2. The trailing slash is missing.

To fix **#1** you can either:

- Hardcode the `/wp` prefix in the substitution string (as is done in the last `RewriteRule` - part of the WordPress front-controller - although that is arguably incorrect, see the *next point*). For example:

  ```
  RewriteRule (.*) /wp/$1? [R=301,L]
  ```
- Since `RewriteBase /wp` is already defined, you can simply remove the slash prefix on the substitution string (to make it a *relative* path substitution). ie. `$1?`. mod_rewrite then prepends the `/wp` path segment to the resulting *substitution*. For example:

  ```
  RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L]
  ```

  *Aside:* This is really how the last `RewriteRule` should be written. ie. `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` (since that's the whole point of having `RewriteBase /wp` defined in the first place).
- Change the rule to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead of a backreference (`$1`). The `REQUEST_URI` contains the full root-relative URL-path, so already includes the `/wp` prefix. This is perhaps the preferred method (unless there are additional requirements) since it will work *anywhere* and is not dependent on the setting of `RewriteBase`. For example:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
  ```

However, this does not resolve **#2** - the missing trailing slash. This is not caused by this directive - something else is removing the trailing slash (if it is present on the initial request). A possible reason for this is the *permalink* structure as suggested in [@IXN's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211012/8259). Providing the trailing slash is part of the initial request (as indicated in the question) then this directive specifically preserves it. If the trailing slash is missing from the initial request then the trailing slash will also be missing from the redirected response (*see below* on how to fix this). In order to debug this further, you should check for any additional redirects in the network traffic.

**Additional notes:**

- You should avoid editing the code within the `# BEGIN WordPress` section, since WordPress will try to maintain this and overwrite your edits. This redirect should go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, before the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.
- `^token=12345` - Include an and-of-string anchor (`$`) on the *CondPattern* to match this query string string only. As it stands, this matches any query string that simply *starts* with `token=12345`.
- On Apache 2.4 use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag instead of appending an empty query string (a lone `?`) on the *substitution* string.
- As it currently stands, this rule matches *any* URL-path. Including all static resources (images, CSS, JS) etc. It doesn't specifically match `/wp/<custom-taxonomy>/<somepagename>/` - the URL format as stated. Ideally, your rule should be as specific as possible, to match only the targetted URLs, so as to avoid unnecessary redirects and additional rule processing. For example:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^[\w-]+/[\w-]+/$ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]
  ```

  The `\w` shorthand character class matches the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_` (underscore) so naturally avoids matching static resources that typically have a file extension prefixed with a *dot*.
- To match an *optional* trailing slash on the initial request, but always include the trailing slash on the redirected URL then you can do something like this:

  ```
  # Trailing slash optional on request and slash always appended
  # (Dependent on RewriteBase)
  RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/[\w-]+)/?$ $1/ [QSD,R=301,L]
  ```

  However, this is now reliant on the `RewriteBase` directive (to get the directory prefix) as mentioned above. Although you could use a *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) to remove the dependency on `RewriteBase`. For example:

  ```
  # Trailing slash optional on request and slash always appended 
  # (Not dependent on RewriteBase)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*?)/?$
  RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/[\w-]+)/?$ %1/ [QSD,R=301,L]
  ```
- Always test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues (301s are cached persistently by the browser - including redirects made in error). Clear the browser cache before testing.

#### In Summary

```
   # Trailing slash optional on request and slash always appended
   # Full URL-path used, including subdirectory preifx
   # Not dependent on RewriteBase
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^token=12345$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*?)/?$
   RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/[\w-]+)/?$ %1/ [QSD,R=301,L]

   # BEGIN WordPress
   :
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) in WordPress to capture the query args or [add_rewrite_endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). If you really just want to redirect based on certain rules then [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) can be a good place to use a header redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your permalink configuration.
It seems that WP redirects

```
www.example.com/slug/somepagename/
```

to

```
www.example.com/slug/somepagename
```

anyway.
If you solve this, probably by setting your permalinks in wp admin, then the redirect will work.

It's funny but I'm doing the exact same thing right now for my site, redirecting mobile queries (?m=1) to the main pages. So I can confirm that your code is correct. The only thing different I do is add $ at the end of the query, like `^token=12345$`, but I don't think this makes a difference.

Comment: I am using custom permalink - /%postname%/. I just added more information about my problem in the question section.. i think the main problem is that i installed wordpress in a folder from domain(example.com/wp), not in the root of the domain.. Also i entered by mistake the /slug/ part, it's a custom taxonomy there, if it helps this information. The token is used for custom acces permission, like in your case for redirecting mobile queries. I tried to add $ but didn't do anything.

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your .htaccess-

```
Redirect 301 /slug/somepagename/?token=12345 http://www.example.com/wp/slug/somepagename/
```

Comment: The `Redirect` directive matches against the URL-path only, not the query string, so the above directive would never match the example URL in the question. (It would also _preserve_ the query string, not remove it, should the URL match.)